# "NameError: name 'update' is not defined" Error when using datatable

Tags: python, pandas, datatable

I am trying datatable in python for first time and was following examples from this link: [Grouping with `by()`](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/groupby_examples.html) to explore more on datatables, but am getting a `NameError` when attempted below code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datatable as dt

df = dt.Frame([[1, 1, 5], [2, 3, 6]], names=['A', 'B'])

df[:, update(filter_col = count()), by('A')]
```

Error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2040/2701559568.py in <module>
----> 1 df[:, update(filter_col = count()), by('A')]

NameError: name 'update' is not defined
```

This is working fine in the example shown in above link but I am not sure why I am getting this error. Also tried help on this:

```
help(update())
```

But got this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2040/1402169417.py in <module>
----> 1 help(update())

NameError: name 'update' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `update` is not imported directly, but through `datatable` (`dt`). You can access it with`dt.update`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the right name to access `update()`. The very first example has:

```
from datatable import (dt, f, by, ifelse, update, sort,
                       count, min, max, mean, sum, rowsum)
```

Meaning that they can refer to `datatable.update` as just `update`.

However your import is like:

```
import datatable as dt
```

Meaning that to access `datatable.update`, you have to use `dt.update`. Same with `datatable.count` and `datatable.by`:

So the solution would look like:

```
df[:, dt.update(filter_col = dt.count()), dt.by('A')]
```

Comment: Thanks @Randon Davis for adding the solution & explanation as well. I don't know why, may be a conflict in libs or all these functions are from `datatable`. I had to specifically add `dt.` to all other functions as well to make this work `df[:, dt.update(filter_col = dt.count()), dt.by('A')]`

Comment: @ViSa anything you're using from `datatable` needs to be prefixed with `dt`. Those things being `dt`, `f`, `by`, `ifelse`, `update`, `sort`, `count`, `min`, `max`, `mean`, `sum`, and `rowsum`, which all were imported directly from `datatable`. The tutorial doesn't prefix them with `dt` because it imported those things from `datatable` differently. I updated my answer to include that info just now.

Comment: Thank you @Random Davis, for elaborating more & helping me on this. Appreciate your help !!